# use Vue.js components as dependency

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a Vue.js (2.6) app that's just a panel for some crud actions for given APIs.
this panel will deploy for several clients and some part of this panel (some components) may not include for specific clients.
my question is how can I separate this "some part of this panel" to act like an addon or dependency so I can add if clients needed? otherwise root project is just enough. is there any library or architecture to do something like that?

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously don't know the details of you Vue app implementation, but a basic way can be to use 'v-if'.  And possibly research lazy loading of child components, as well a logical way of initializing the values of 'includeChildOne', 'includeChildTwo', etc.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h3>Parent.vue</h3>
    <hr>
    <child-one v-if="includeChildOne" />
    <child-two v-if="includeChildTwo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildOne from './ChildOne.vue'
  import ChildTwo from './ChildTwo.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      ChildOne,
      ChildTwo
    },
    data() {
      return {
        includeChildOne: false,
        includeChildTwo: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

ChildOne.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child-one">
    <h4>ChildOne.vue</h4>
  </div>
</template>
```

ChildTwo.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child-two">
    <h4>ChildTwo.vue</h4>
  </div>
</template>
```